# How can I layer two <div>s in a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox container that has two `<div>`s in it.  One of the `<div>`s is the header, and the other `<div>` is hidden until an event is fired. When said event is fired, I want to make the hidden `<div>` appear on top of the other.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header {
  max-width: 600px;
}

#content {
  display: none;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.changed #content {
  display: block;
  z-index: 100;
}

.changed .header {
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <div class="icons">Icons</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

The class `.changed` is the class added to `.container` that renders the `#content` `<div>` visible.  This part works fine.

The problem is that the `.header` and the `#content` `<div>`s are appearing side-by-side, even though they each have different `z-index` values. I think this is because of flexbox.

I've tried using different methods of horizontal and vertical centering, but flexbox has gotten me the closest to what I want.  Is this the right approach and I'm just missing something?  Should I go about this a different way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you adding vendor prefixes? If not, try running it through https://autoprefixer.github.io

Comment: Yes, it doesn't affect anything though.  I didn't include them here in the samples for brevity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Stack the flex items in a column:

  ```
  .container { flex-direction: column; }
  ```
- Make the container the containing block for absolute positioning:

  ```
  .container { position: relative; }
  ```
- Absolutely position the hidden div over the header:

  ```
  #content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  ```

Then apply your JS and `z-index` as necessary.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

#content {
  /* display: none; */
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.changed #content {
  /* display: block; <-- not necessary */
  z-index: 100;
}

.changed .header {
  opacity: .3;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h2>Subheading</h2>
    <div class="icons">Icons</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">HIDDEN DIV
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `flex-direction: column;` and set the `order`

http://jsbin.com/cuximuhemi/edit?html,css,output

Is that what you’re going for?

Comment: Ah, sorry I was unclear, I don't mean "on top" as if they were a column, I mean on top as if one div was covered by the other, like on the z-axis, not the y.

Comment: Oh, ok. If you want one element to overlap another, your best bet is probably absolute positioning. I updated the JSBin http://jsbin.com/cuximuhemi/edit?html,css,output Let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Okay, because of this approach, the <div>s won't be horizontally and vertically centered on the page anymore.  Is there a quick way to do this without having to mess with the width and the height?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot about the centering! I don't have time to update right now, but this article breaks down all the ways to center https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ Honestly, I would try to avoid the flexbox approach if possible due to various cross-browser bugs (see https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs). It's great for small components, but I would hesitate to use it for the main layout of a site.

Comment: You are required to post your markup here, not a third party site which can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one. Either post your markup here or delete this altogether.